# How to float an infobox right with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an infobox on my Jekyll site with the HTML source code:

```
<table style="width: 1000px; border: 1px; padding: 1em; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; float:right;">
  <tbody style="width: 1000px; float:right;">
    <caption id="table-1" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">
      {{ include.distro }}
    </caption>
    <tr class="cyan">
      <td class="white" colspan="2"><img src="/images/Logos/{{ include.logo }}" style = "width:100px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Characteristics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1">Category</td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.category }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The country this distribution originated from. It may nowadays be developed by people from a variety of different countries.">Country</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.country }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The year that this distribution was official first announced or released">Date</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.date }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Who develops this distro? Is it developed by a community or a company?">Developed by</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.developer }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Where does the funding for this distribution come from?">Funded by</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.funding }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The default init system of the latest release of this distribution">Init system</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.init-system }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The default package manager of the latest release of this distribution">Package manager</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.package-manager }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The release model of this distribution">Release model</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.release-model }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Officially supported CPU architectures for all presently supported releases">Architectures</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.architecture }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for Broadcom wireless?">Broadcom</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.broadcom }}">{{ include.broadcom }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for Filesystem in Userspace?">FUSE</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.fuse }}">{{ include.fuse }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Presently supported releases">Releases</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.releases }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for UEFI firmware?">UEFI</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.uefi }}">{{ include.uefi }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Software</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of Mozilla Firefox in the official repositories of this distribution">Firefox</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.firefox }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of glibc in the official repositories of this distribution">glibc</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.glibc }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of GNOME Shell in the official repositories of this distribution">GNOME</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.gnome }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of LibreOffice in the official repositories of this distribution">LibreOffice</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.libreoffice }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of the Linux kernel in the official repositories of this distribution">Linux</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.linux }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of the Xorg in the official repositories of this distribution">Xorg</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.xorg }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% include Layouts/clear.html %}
```

where `{% include ... %}` and `{{ include... }}` are Liquid tags. `Layouts/clear.html` is [here](https://github.com/fusion809/fusion809.github.io/blob/master/_includes/Layouts/clear.html), it is designed to ensure that headings (later in the article) don't overlap with this infobox. This infobox is included in a post with the code:

```
{% include_relative table.html distro="Arch Linux" logo="ArchLinux.svg" category="Minimalist" country="Canada" date="2002" developer="Community" funding="Donations" init-system="systemd" package-manager="pacman" release-model="Rolling" architecture="arm, i686, x86_64" broadcom="AUR" fuse="Yes" uefi="Yes" firefox="50.1.0" glibc="2.24" gnome="3.22.2+18+gdf7727a" libreoffice="5.2.3" linux="4.8.14" xorg="1.19.0" %}
```

and for some reason it is rendered as:

[image]

note how it is centred even though in the first line of my HTML code (`<table style="width: 1000px; border: 1px; padding: 1em; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; float:right;">`) you can see I had the style `float:right;`. Examining the code with Chrome's element inspector show's that the `<table>` has the `float` display property set to `right`. Likewise `<tbody>` also has the `float` display property set to `right`. `<caption>` has the `float` property set to `none` and all other subelements of the table like `<tr>` and `<td>` have no `float` property set.

EDIT: If you want to try out solutions to my fixing issues, merely run (assuming you're running Linux and have rubygems installed):

```
git clone https://github.com/fusion809/fusion809.github.io # warning this repo is over 70 MB in size!
cd fusion809.github.io
sudo gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve -D --future
```

then open your browser to http://localhost/comparison-major-linux, where `localhost` can be replaced with wherever Jekyll is generating this site locally on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Turns out it was related to the width assignment in the `<table>` and `<tbody>` tags. Now with:

```
<table style="width: 400px; border: 1px; padding: 1em; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; float:right;">
  <tbody style="width: 400px; float:right;">
    <caption id="table-1" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">
      {{ include.distro }}
    </caption>
    <tr class="cyan">
      <td class="white" colspan="2"><img src="/images/Logos/{{ include.logo }}" style = "width:100px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Characteristics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1" style="width: 100px;">Category</td>
      <td class="green" style="width: 300px;">{{ include.category }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The country this distribution originated from. It may nowadays be developed by people from a variety of different countries.">Country</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.country }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The year that this distribution was official first announced or released">Date</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.date }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Who develops this distro? Is it developed by a community or a company?">Developed by</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.developer }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Where does the funding for this distribution come from?">Funded by</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.funding }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The default init system of the latest release of this distribution">Init system</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.init-system }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The default package manager of the latest release of this distribution">Package manager</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.package-manager }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The release model of this distribution">Release model</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.release-model }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Officially supported CPU architectures for all presently supported releases">Architectures</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.architecture }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for Broadcom wireless?">Broadcom</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.broadcom }}">{{ include.broadcom }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for Filesystem in Userspace?">FUSE</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.fuse }}">{{ include.fuse }}</td>
    </tr>{% if include.releases %}
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Presently supported releases">Releases</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.releases }}</td>
    </tr>{% endif %}
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="Does this distribution have out-of-the-box support for UEFI firmware?">UEFI</abbr></td>
      <td class="{{ include.uefi }}">{{ include.uefi }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Software</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of Bash in the official repositories of this distribution">Bash</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.bash }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of Mozilla Firefox in the official repositories of this distribution">Firefox</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.firefox }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of glibc in the official repositories of this distribution">glibc</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.glibc }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of GNOME Shell in the official repositories of this distribution">GNOME</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.gnome }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of LibreOffice in the official repositories of this distribution">LibreOffice</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.libreoffice }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of the Linux kernel in the official repositories of this distribution">Linux</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.linux }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of the Xorg in the official repositories of this distribution">Xorg</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.xorg }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <td class="title1"><abbr title="The latest version of the Zsh in the official repositories of this distribution">Zsh</abbr></td>
      <td class="green">{{ include.zsh }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% include Layouts/clear.html %}
```

it works.